# Как реализовать релевантный поиск файлов (mp3)с помощью PHP?

Tags: php

```
<body>
<?php

$song_name   = $_POST['name_s'];
$song_author = $_POST['author_s'];
$song_year   = $_POST['year_s'];
$song_album  = $_POST['album_s'];
$song_dir    = $_POST['dir_s'];
/*директория с песней*/

echo "Директория: " . $song_dir . '<br>';
echo "Имя песни: " . $song_name . '<br>';
echo "Автор песни: " . $song_author . '<br>';
echo "Год записи песни: " . $song_year . '<br>';
echo "Альбом песни: " . $song_album . '<br>';

$handle   = opendir($song_dir);
$filename = 'visits.txt';
if ($handle != false) {
    if (is_writable($filename)) {
        $f = fopen('visits.txt', 'w+');

        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != '..' && $file != '.') {
                fwrite($f, $file . "\n");
            }
        }
        fclose($f);
    } else {
        echo "Не могу произвести запись в файл $filename ";
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

?>
<?php

echo 'Альбомы песни!<br/>';
$lines = file('visits.txt');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    $directory = trim($song_dir . $lines[$i]);

    echo "Выводим файлы каталога $directory";
    if (is_dir($directory)) {
        /*открываем каждую папку*/
        if ($handle2 = opendir("$directory")) {
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle2))) {
                if ($file != '..' && $file != '.') {
                    echo "$file <br>";
                }
            }
            closedir($handle2);
        }
    } else {
        echo "Неправильная директория </br>";

    }
}
?>
</body>
```

Необходимо создать приложение на PHP, состоящее из двух программ: программы кэширования и программы поиска. Программа кэширования должна исследовать заданную директорию с музыкальными файлами на жёстком диске, разложенными в поддиректории. Результат исследования должен быть сохранён в текстовый файл, чтобы его могла использовать вторая программа. При исследовании необходимо определить имя файла и его полный путь в файловой системе. Если имя файла содержит год записи композиции, исполнителя или альбом, их необходимо отдельно сохранить в кэш-файл, связав с музыкальным файлом.
Вторая программа – программа поиска – должна в качестве параметра при запуске принимать название композиции, исполнителя, год записи, альбом. Пользователь может ввести один из указанных критериев или несколько. Критерии могут быть заданы целиком или частично. Например, при поиске композиции «I won’t go Hollywood» пользователь может указать только слово «Hollywood». Программа должна найти в кэш-файле соответствующие поисковым критериям записи и показать полный путь к найденным файлам в виде списка, расставляя записи в релевантном порядке.

PS. Я вывод файлов сделал, а дальше ступор (нужно по полному пути вычленить как-то названия песни, альбома, год записи, как это сделать? Я так понял разделить слешами полный путь, потом просто пробегаться по каждой строке и искать. Если совпали все слова, то присвоить индекс 1, если 2 то индекс 2 и т д. Еще не могу полный путь записать в файл, пробовал функцией glob, но там если на конце была квадратная скобка у папки. Не опознавал ее как папку. Использовал вот такой прием.

---

```
$dir = 'C:\Temp';
foreach (glob("$dir\\*.txt") as $filepath) {
      echo 'short name: ' . basename($filepath) . ' | ';
      echo "full path: $filepath | ";
      echo 'size :' . filesize($filepath) . "\n";
} //
```

Answer (score 1):

Подумай каким может быть формат самих имен файлов учитывая дополнительные данные по году, альбому и т.д. Запиши их все возможные в какой-то пример и подумай что общего. В этих записях. Например:
artist_name-song name
artist name_song-na-me
и т.д.
далее для каждой записи, к формату составь шаблон поиска используя preg* функции(preg_match например). Работай с шаблонами.